# Save an entity and all its related entities in a single save in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot,REST and JPA to build my application. 
In app, there are 4 entities with one to many relationship.

Is it possible to save multiple entities in one save operation?

Please help!

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChildA> childA = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChildB> childB = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChildC> childC = new ArrayList<>();

    ... getter and setter ...

}
```

**ChildA.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChildA{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;

    public void setParent(Parent parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    ... getter and setter ...
}
```

**ChildB.java** and **ChildC.java** are similar to ChildA.java

**Repository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface repository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

}
```

I want save this json.

```
{
  "name": "parent-name",
  "childA": [
    {
      "name": "parent-childA"
    }
  ],
  "childB": [
    {
      "name": "parent-childB"
    }
  ],
  "childC": [
    {
      "name": "parent-childC"
    }
  ]
}
```

**DB**

```
Parent
id   |   name
5        parent-name

ChildA
id   |   parent-id  |  name
 1   |       5      |  parent-childA

ChildB
id   |   parent-id  |  name
 1   |       5      |  parent-childA

ChildC
id   |   parent-id  |  name
 1   |       5      |  parent-childA
```

Comment: May I ask a counter question. What is your expected advantage?

Comment: Just put all the repository calls inside a single transaction, then you will have multiple SQL statements run inside a single transaction.  The transaction is the largest overhead, the network call is minimal.  Usually overall the performance advantage is minimal.

Comment: Please post how you are saving, you can achieve this using repositary.save(object). The only thing you need to do use set by directional mapping. i.e for each child you you should set child.setParent(parent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer.
Thanks for the reply.

```
@RestController
public class ParentController {
    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @PutMapping("")
    public void save(@RequestBody @Valid Parent parent) {
        parentRepository.save(parent);

    }
```

**Parent.java** add @JsonManagedReference

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ChildA> childA = new ArrayList<>();
```

And Child class
**ChildA.java, ChildB.java, ChildC.java** add @JsonBackReference

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
private Parent parent;
```